# How to show $X=\{A\in\mathcal{L}(\mathbb R^m, \mathbb R^n); \textrm{Ker}(A)=\{0\}\}$ is open in $\mathcal{L}(\mathbb R^m, \mathbb R^n)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, general-topology, matrices, vector-spaces

How to show $X=\{A\in\mathcal{L}(\mathbb R^m, \mathbb R^n); \textrm{Ker}(A)=\{0\}\}$ is open in $\mathcal{L}(\mathbb R^m, \mathbb R^n)$?

Here $\mathcal{L}(\mathbb R^m, \mathbb R^n)$ is the set of all linear applications between $\mathbb R^m$ and $\mathbb R^n$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a alternative with sequences and local compactness.

Let us prove that the complement of $X$, i.e.
$$
X^c=\{A:\mathbb{R}^m\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}^n\;;\;\mbox{Ker}\;A\neq\{0\}\}
$$
is (sequentially) closed.

So assume $A_k$ is a sequence of $X^c$ which converges to $A$ for the operator norm.

For every $k$, there exists a unit vector $\|x_k\|=1$ in $\mathbb{R}^m$ such that $A_kx_k=0$. By local compactness of the finite-dimensional normed vector space $\mathbb{R}^m$, there exists a subsequence $x_{n_k}$ which converges to $x$. By continuity of the norm, we have $\|x\|=1$ (or for short, we could have used the compactness of the unit sphere directly). Now 
$$
\|Ax\|=\|A(x-x_{n_k})+(A-A_{n_k})x_{n_k}\|\leq \|A\|\|x-x_{n_k}\|+\|A-A_{n_k}\|\|x_k\|
$$
$$
=\|A\|\|x-x_{n_k}\|+\|A-A_{n_k}\|\longrightarrow 0.
$$
Hence $Ax=0$ and $A$ is not injective, i.e. $A$ belongs to $X^c$.

Comment: @PtF You're welcome. Glad it helped. Note that I would normally do it like Jared.

Answer (score 7):

Notice if $m>n$, then $X=\varnothing$ is open.  So suppose $m\le n$.

Identify $\mathcal{L}(\mathbb{R}^m,\mathbb{R}^n)$ with $\mathbb{M}_{n\times m}(\mathbb{R})$.  Notice that for $A\in\mathbb{M}_{n\times m}(\mathbb{R})$, $\ker(A)=0$ if and only if rank$(A)=m$ if and only if the determinant of some $m\times m$ submatrix of $A$ is nonzero.  This shows that $X^c$ is the intersection of the inverse images of $0\in\mathbb{R}$ of polynomial functions defining the determinants of $m\times m$ submatrices of $A$.  Polynomials are continuous, and $\{0\}$ is closed, hence $X^c$ is closed, and $X$ is open.

For further concreteness, there are $\binom{n}{m}$ square submatrices of size $m$.  If we consider a matrix of variables $x_{ij}$, then we obtain $\binom{n}{m}$ polynomial functions $p_1,\ldots,p_{r}\in\mathbb{R}[x_{ij}]$ which represent the determinants of each $m\times m$ submatrix, where $r=\binom{n}{m}$.  Each $p_i$ defines a map $\mathbb{M}_{n\times m}(\mathbb{R})\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ simply by evaluating at the entries of a real matrix.  If $A\in X^c$, then $A$ must map to $0\in\mathbb{R}$ under all of the $p_i$.  Hence, we have

$$X^c=\bigcap_{i=1}^{r}p_i^{-1}(0)$$

Comment: Thanks for the help, cool solutions.. Now I was wondering if there is a way to define a continuous map $T:\mathcal{L}(\mathbb R^m, \mathbb R^n)\rightarrow X$ such that $A=T^{-1}(B)$ for some $B$ open in this set $X$.. Do you have any idea?

Comment: Something isn't right here.  If you want $T$ to be continuous, and $B$ to be open in $X$, then $T^{-1}(B)$ will be open, but the single point $A$ is not open.

Comment: I wrote it all wrong, I ended up confounding the notation.. I meant, is it possible defining $T:\mathcal{L}(\mathbb R^m, \mathbb R^n)\rightarrow Z$ (for some set $Z$) such that $X=T^{-1}(B)$ for some open $B\subset Z$?

Comment: Sure.  Just map $\mathcal{L}(\mathbb{R}^m,\mathbb{R}^n)$ to the space $Z$ which is $\binom{n}{m}$ copies of $\mathbb{R}$, under the determinantal polynomials.  Then $X$ will be the inverse image of the open set in $Z$ which is the complement of the union of the coordinate axes.

Comment: Very interesting @Jared, thanks =D

Comment: My previous comment is wrong, we should actually take the open set $B\subset Z$ to be the complement of the origin.