# How to show $A=\{T\in \mathcal{L}(\mathbb R^m, \mathbb R^n); \textrm{T is onto}\}$ is open in $\mathcal{L}(\mathbb R^m, \mathbb R^n)$

Tags: linear-algebra, general-topology, matrices, normed-spaces

How can we show $A=\{T\in \mathcal{L}(\mathbb R^m, \mathbb R^n); \textrm{T is onto}\}$ is open in $\mathcal{L}(\mathbb R^m, \mathbb R^n)$?

Here $\mathcal{L}(\mathbb R^m, \mathbb R^n)$ is the set of all linear transformations between $\mathbb R^m$ and $\mathbb R^n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Observe that $T$ is onto if and only if the adjoint $T^*$ is injective. Then use [the result you have just asked about](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/351562/how-to-show-x-a-in-mathcall-mathbb-rm-mathbb-rn-textrmkera-0). And the fact that $T\longmapsto T^*$ is a homeomorphism.

If you want to make this slightly easier, do it with matrices $T$. Then $T^*$ is simply the transpose of $T$. You know that the rank of $T$ is equal to the rank of $T^*$.

On one hand, the rank of $T$ is equal to its column rank. So $T$ is onto if and only if $\mbox{rank} \;T=n$.

On the other hand, the rank-nullity theorem yields $\mbox{rank}\;T^*=n-\dim\mbox{Ker }\;T^*$. So $T^*$ is injective if and only if $\mbox{rank}\;T^*=n$.

Comment: Very smart solution, I'll supply the details, thanks again =D

Comment: This is a nice solution.  I was trying to relate this question to the previous problem too, but didn't think of this.